# Select2 Ajax function not returning data to select box

Tags: ajax, coffeescript, jquery-select2

In my coffeescript I have this setup

```
$ajaxSelect = $('select.ajax-select').select2
        ajax:
            url: (params) ->
                return "/mppc-people-manager/users/find_users/#{params.term}"
            delay: 250
            dataType: 'json'
            data: (params) ->
                console.log params
            processResults: (data) ->
                console.log data
                formatted = []
                $.each data, (i, val) ->
                    console.log val
                    formatted.push
                        id: val.User.id
                        text: "<img src='#{val.User.photo_filename}' class='face'><span class='name'>#{val.User.full_name}</span>"
                    return {
                        results: formatted
                    }
```

The json returned from my url looks like this

```
[  
   {  
      "User":{  
         "id":"557ae341-b618-4028-8b93-496216ed9843",
         "photo_filename":"photos\/558bec2e-2eb8-404c-a344-462816ed9843\/selfie-stick.jpg",
         "full_name":"Jordan Riser"
      }
   }
]
```

I copied the format that I saw in the examples right above the ajax example where each array item is an object that each contain an `id:` and `text:` value, but is this not the correct format?

The ajax example and documentation just explain that it needs to be returned the in way select2 expects but what exactly does that mean?

Any direction here would be great!

Comment: `[
  {
    "User":{
      "id":"557ae341-b618-4028-8b93-496216ed9843",
      "photo_filename":"photos\/558bec2e-2eb8-404c-a344-462816ed9843\/selfie-stick.jpg",
      "full_name":"Jordan Riser"
    }
  }
]`
is a `console.log data` output?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got it working by just passing an array of objects containing `id:` and `text:` elements in each object from the backend and then passing that to the results returned from the `processResults` function. Here is my coffeescript to pass the results

```
$ajaxSelect = $('select.ajax-select').select2
        placeholder: "Select a state"
        ajax:
            delay: 250
            dataType: 'json'
            cache: false
            processResults: (data,page) ->
                { results: $.map data, (item,i) ->
                    {
                        text: item.text
                        slug: null
                        id: item.id
                    }
                }
        minimumInputLength: 1
        templateSelection: (selection) ->
            return $.parseHTML(selection.text)
        templateResult: (result) ->
            return $.parseHTML(result.text)
```

I won't show my backend code because it's irreleveant to this question, just know I passed it something that looks like this

```
[{
    id: 1,
    text: 'Text'
},{
    id: 2,
    text: 'Text'
}]
```